# jstree infinite tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jstree

Jstree code -

```
$("#jstree").jstree({ 
   "json_data" : {
       "ajax" : {
           "url" : "Servlet?action=view&docId=100,
       }
   },
});
```

Now, what is happening is when I expand any of the leaf node then the whole tree builds under that.

The same problem is also observed here - http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data#demo2
Try to expand the "Only Child" node and the whole tree builds under that.

Can I remove the ajax request from node expanding because in my case all the tree is loaded at once.

Comment: Not sure if I understood. jsTree displays whatever ajax returns...

Comment: you can see the link to understand what I am saying. Otherwise if there is a way to disable ajax calls on node expansion then that would do good for me.

Comment: use `"state" : "closed",` for node in case you don't ajax call to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `state:leaf` for nodes that do not open.
every time you open a node in jstree it fires an ajax request with the opened node parameters so you get an infinite tree.